# How can I handle Mongoid errors in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongoid

Is it possible to write an error handler in my Sinatra app that will handles errors coming from Mongoid? For example, can I write a method that will handle a DocumentNotFound exception from Mongoid?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can!

Write an error handler for the Mongoid exception in Sinatra:

```
error Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound do
  #pass the id's to the view
  haml :mongoiderror, :locals => { :ids => request.env['sinatra.error'].identifiers }
end
```